# Python BeautifulSoup Error

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup, lxml, html5lib

I have this script:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
import lxml

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hitmeister.de").read())
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "akaConnection.py", line 59, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hitmeister.de").read())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1499, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1263, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(markup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 148, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 226, in parse_starttag
    endpos = self.check_for_whole_start_tag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 301, in check_for_whole_start_tag
    self.error("malformed start tag")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 115, in error
    raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos())
HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 56, column 872
```

Then I tried this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hitmeister.de").read(),"lxml")
```

or

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hitmeister.de").read(),"html5lib")
```

This gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "akaConnection.py", line 59, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hitmeister.de").read(),"lxml")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1499, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1263, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(markup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 156, in goahead
    k = self.parse_declaration(i)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1112, in parse_declaration
    j = HTMLParser.parse_declaration(self, i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/markupbase.py", line 109, in parse_declaration
    self.handle_decl(data)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1097, in handle_decl
    self._toStringSubclass(data, Declaration)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1030, in _toStringSubclass
    self.soup.endData(subclass)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1318, in endData
    (not self.parseOnlyThese.text or \
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I am running Linux Ubuntu 10.04, Python 2.6.5, BeautifulSoup version is : '3.1.0.1' 
How can I fix my code, or is there something what I missed?

Comment: Your initial script seems to work for me.... What version of BeautifulSoup do you have? Mine is 3.0.8.1.

Comment: For really broken HTML, another option is to run it through Tidy first. Something like http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib

Comment: The second error is from copying an example for BeautifulSoup 4 and trying to use it with BeautifulSoup 3. BS3 doesn't use lxml or html5lib.

Comment: Mine BeautifulSoup version is : '3.1.0.1'

Comment: "BS3 doesn't use lxml or html5lib" then how can I fix it, I can not install another python version, because it is on server, and also as I know BS4 is not support for python <2.7, any suggestions?

Comment: If your host is still running 2.6.5, you might consider finding a new host. Not saying it's a solution, but that's pretty out of date. I get people not on 3.x at this point, but not even 2.7.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments, please use [`pytidylib`](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib)...

```
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from tidylib import tidy_document

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hitmeister.de").read()
tidy, errors = tidy_document(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(tidy)
print type(soup)
```

Running this...

```
(py26_default)[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python foo.py
<class 'BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup'>
(py26_default)[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

---

The `errors` from `pytidylib` were:

```
line 53 column 1493 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 53 column 1518 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 53 column 1541 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 53 column 1547 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 132 column 239 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 135 column 231 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 434 column 98 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 156
line 453 column 96 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 156
line 780 column 108 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 159
line 991 column 27 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 156
line 1018 column 43 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1029 column 40 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1037 column 126 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1039 column 96 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1040 column 71 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1041 column 58 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1047 column 126 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1049 column 96 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1050 column 72 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1051 column 58 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1063 column 108 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1066 column 58 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1076 column 17 - Warning: <input> element not empty or not closed
line 1121 column 140 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1202 column 33 - Error: <g:plusone> is not recognized!
line 1202 column 33 - Warning: discarding unexpected <g:plusone>
line 1202 column 88 - Warning: discarding unexpected </g:plusone>
line 1245 column 86 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1265 column 33 - Warning: entity "&gt" doesn't end in ';'
line 1345 column 354 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here
line 1361 column 255 - Warning: unescaped & or unknown entity "&_s_icmp"
line 1361 column 562 - Warning: unescaped & or unknown entity "&_s_icmp"
line 1361 column 856 - Warning: unescaped & or unknown entity "&_s_icmp"
line 1397 column 115 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1425 column 116 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1453 column 115 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1481 column 116 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1509 column 116 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1523 column 251 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 159
line 1524 column 259 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 159
line 1524 column 395 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 159
line 1533 column 151 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 159
line 1537 column 115 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1565 column 116 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1593 column 116 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1621 column 115 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1649 column 115 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1677 column 115 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1705 column 115 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1750 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1774 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1798 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1822 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1826 column 78 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1854 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1878 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1902 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1926 column 150 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 130
line 1954 column 186 - Warning: unescaped & or unknown entity "&charge"
line 2004 column 100 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 156
line 2033 column 162 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 159
line 21 column 1 - Warning: <meta> proprietary attribute "property"
line 22 column 1 - Warning: <meta> proprietary attribute "property"
line 23 column 1 - Warning: <meta> proprietary attribute "property"
line 29 column 1 - Warning: <meta> proprietary attribute "property"
line 30 column 1 - Warning: <meta> proprietary attribute "property"
line 31 column 1 - Warning: <meta> proprietary attribute "property"
line 412 column 9 - Warning: <body> proprietary attribute "itemscope"
line 412 column 9 - Warning: <body> proprietary attribute "itemtype"
line 1143 column 1 - Warning: <script> inserting "type" attribute
line 1225 column 44 - Warning: <table> lacks "summary" attribute
line 1934 column 9 - Warning: <div> proprietary attribute "name"
line 436 column 41 - Warning: trimming empty <li>
line 446 column 89 - Warning: trimming empty <li>
line 1239 column 33 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1747 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1771 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1795 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1819 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1851 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1875 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1899 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 1923 column 37 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 2018 column 49 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
line 2026 column 49 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
```

Comment: Maybe this question is not releted to BS, but I am new to python, can you. please, explain, this line: tidy, errors = tidy_document(html).

Comment: `tidy` is the html document cleaned up by `pytidylib`, and `errors` are the errors `pytidylib` found in the original I sent to it.

Comment: you just assign two variables in one line, am I right? I wanted to know that

Comment: correct, `tidy_document` returns two values: a sanitized html string and errors found during the html sanitization.

Comment: Mike Pennington, nice explanation of a feature that confused me about python as a n00b (and one that I quickly came to love)

Answer (score 0):

There are version dependencies with urllib and urllib2. 
I whave done the same thing by:

```
sock=urllib.urlopen("http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/903603.html")
```

htmlSource=sock.read()

I was using soup.find_all by attributes. Hope this was helpful